# Have async function in useEffect return the cleanup function for the useEffect itself

Tags: reactjs, react-typescript

It is easy to call an `async` function in `useEffect`. Roughly:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fun = async () => {}
  fun();
}, []);
```

But now, assume my async function returns the cleanup function for the useEffect. How can I properly return the cleanup function?

```
useEffect(() => {
  const fun = async () => {
    // some async stuff here
    return () => "cleanup";
  }
  return fun(); // err because fun returns a promise
}, []);
```

Context: This is a real world problem. My `async` function is defined outside of the `useEffect` and loads data from a remote service. The function is also wrapped in `useCallback`. When the fetching fails it adds a notification to a list of notifications. In React strict mode `useEffect` is called twice. Thus I want to remove the notification on cleanup and the cleanup itself heavily depends on the notification pushed so I can't define the cleanup function outside of the `async` function. I also can't move the `async` function inside of `useEffect` because this function is used by multiple components. :x

Comment: You _can't_ return the cleanup function if it's defined inside the asynchronous context, because the cleanup function needs to be returned synchronously. What's the actual context here?

Comment: Is this a theoretical question or is there an actual use case for this?

Comment: Thank you both. I added more context to the initial question.

Comment: You can run `useEffect` once even in strict mode.  Take a look at [this](https://github.com/reactwg/react-18/discussions/18)  under `Effects that should only run once can use a ref.`

Comment: Store your cleanup function a state or in a ref.

Comment: Can't you just check your list of notifications before adding one so you will not need a cleanup function to begin with?

Comment: `useEffect` is called twice by design. It's not a bug and the React developers literally want us to clean up properly. So using a ref, making sure the message is pushed only once or any other strategy that ensures the `useEffect` is only run once pretty much counters WHY it runs twice in the first place and should never be the solution. I would therefore say that @jonrsharpe 's comment should be an answer which I would accept.

Comment: I posted a link written by react maintainers, here is another https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/synchronizing-with-effects#fetching-data

Comment: @Pagenotfound As far as I understand the phrase 'by design', it is not so. See initial design in the React old docs: 'If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and unmount), you can pass an empty array ([]) as a second argument.' That was a design. What they do now is a change braking design.

Answer (score 0):

You *can not* return the clean-up function from an asynchronous function.

But further more: ***You shouldn't want to***. I.e. there is probably something wrong if the [`useEffect`](https://react.dev/reference/react/useEffect)s clean-up function depends on the result of the `fetch`.

See also: [Synchronizing with Effects](https://react.dev/learn/synchronizing-with-effects).

*(I know there are non-trivial use cases, which I'd be interested to hear,
but more information would be necessary to find a specific solution.)*

The first question to ask yourself probably should be:
Why can running `useEffect` twice have different results ?

I.e. fetching the same data twice - even if that is a redundant network request - *should* have
the same *effective result*, as far as the function of the app is concerned. E.g.
fetching "some data" twice would result in duplicated data, but you ideally would fetch "data with id x", which would when fetched twice have the same result.

### Dirty work-around

Theoretically, depending on your circumstances,
you could work around this in a **"dirty"** way, e.g. by storing some flags or
the clean-up function itself in a `state` or `ref`, similar to this:

```
// ----------------------
// BAD EXAMPLE:
// ----------------------

const cleanUpFromAsync = useRef( null );

const fun = async () => {
    // some async stuff here
    cleanUpFromAsync.current = () => {
        // ...
    };
}

useEffect( () => {
    fun();
    return () => {
        if( typeof cleanUpFromAsync.current === 'function' ){
            cleanUpFromAsync.current();
        }
    }
}, [] );
```

### Better choices

But, instead of cleaning up the results of the fetch,
the `useEffect` should better:
1. cancel the fetch on-cleanup, or if not possible
2. ignore the result

If really even both of these are not possible, you still can:
3. Build a more sophisticated data handler
4. use some last-resort-workaround with useRef

Regarding that "data handler", that really depends on your use case, so I haven't the
details to think of a proper solution, but it would manage the state,
preventing duplicates, and - if necessary - provide a `cleanUp`, `cancel` or `reset` function to the outside. Maybe something like this:

```
const dataHandler = function(){
    const notifications = [];

    const fetchFailed = function( uuid, error ){
        if( checkTheNotificationsSomehow() ){
            notifications.push({ id: uuid, text: 'notification ...' });
        }
    };

    // ...

    return {
        fetch: function(){
            const uuid = createUUID();
            fetch('...').then(
                response => { handleResponse( uuid, response ); },
                error => { fetchFailed( uuid, error ); }
            );
            return uuid;
        },
        cancel: function( uuid ){
            cancelTheFetch( uuid );
            cleanUpNotificationsIfNecessary( uuid );
            // ...
        },
    }
};

// ...

useEffect( () => {
    const uuid = dataHandler.fetch();
    return () => {
        dataHandler.cancel( uuid );
    }
}, [] );
```

Comment: The idea about "we shouldn't even want to do it" looks wrong for me. Well, I should want to. If the useEffect designed to be idempotent, is there another way how to perform action on initialization, which mutates or creates something? And there is nothing untrivial in this situation, this is just usual task.

Comment: Can you tell you exact use case ? What kind of asynchronous, non-idempotent initialization do you need ? I suspect there are either other ways than useEffect, or the initialization can safely be done multiple times, ... or something else.

Comment: ... well, you might miss usual plain JS ways to do something. You can still do plain JS as much as you want, but then you are not using React anymore. E.g. initialize something outside of React however you want, and feed that into a React context or a Redux store before entering the "React world". But if you want the benefits of using React, then you need to follow the principles of React.

Comment: there are a lot of examples. For example, you need to call an API to tell that user starts using the feature, and tell when user exit it. It is just simplest case. I have much more examples, which makes it really unusable, if you trying to build something with workers, using hardware initialization etc.

Comment: regarding you second comment, what the point in such principles, when the initial design says, well, that the hook with empty array is called once by definition, and can be cleared by lambda in return, and later implementation of the design introduced calling it twice?? It is not a principle, it is a handicap to force lazy devs to test their code like a last resort to manage those, but it's just making everything even worse, became really unusable. So I don't see how the high rethoric about 'principles' could be applied here at all.

Comment: The hook with an empty array is not _"called once by definition"_, it is executed **at "initial render"**,  but the component could be rendered and destroyed more than once. React does make tradeoffs. The components are rendered repeatedly (whenever something needs to be updated), so that state management becomes easy, but at some points you need to follow specific rules. Some things become harder..

Comment: I meant it was designed to be called once _in_lifetime_ of the component of course. So I gave you simple use case, when I need to call async API once in lifetime of the component on initial render, and on cleanup. Now, tell me why I 'should not want it' - because it is tradoff? No, it is not designed as a tradoff. They just broke it, lets admit. And there is no way now to make it work back without event more clutches. From the React documentation: 'If you want to run an effect and clean it up only *once* (on mount and unmount), you can pass an empty array ([]) as a second argument.'

Comment: I suggest you create a new question with the details of your use case. I would be interested to have a look at it.

Comment: There is commonly known solution for this semaphoring via flags in stable refs. Or you can use globals, as you said, out of the React, with one gotcha - Nextjs is not doing well with its server-side mess, and it is most robust way to manage the react apps this days. Do we really need to have all this boilerplate? Why we have async event model, if we need to rule out this cases as it happen in truly parallel systems? Of course if you don't build interactively rich apps in multitier architectures, you don't see this cases.

Comment: Here is a non-trivial use case: There is an external service that you want to connect to when a component mounts (for example, a messaging server that will push web socket packets) and disconnect from when the component dismounts (in the cleanup function)
In React strict mode, the component will be mounted/unmounted quickly the first time, so the cleanup function will be called (disconnect from service) before the async code (connect to service) has finished, so there will be an error disconnecting from a service before we are actually connected to it

Comment: @TimF: I guess you can use a `useRef` to store the connection, and only disconnect it if it was connected before. It shouldn't be possible anyway to disconnect a connection that was not connected (With or without React). Alternatively, I would maybe write a global "connection manager" object, that checks the connection before disconnection attempts.